# Get response in Django testing?

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with getting response in django testing
this is the problem appear in terminal

```
    self.assertEquals(self.response.status_code, 200)
AttributeError: 'StoreCreateTest' object has no attribute 'response'
```

This is the command

```
py manage.py test
```

This is my def

```
 def test_store_create_view_status_code(self):
        self.assertEquals(self.response.status_code, 200)
```

and this is my import

```
from django.test import TestCase
from configuration.models import Stores
```

please help me getting this.

Comment: Please share the full `TestCase`. Where do you set the `self.response = ...`?